# Need help finding the rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I'm having a hard time understanding what "rank" really means in terms of matrices.

For example, I've been asked to
Find the rank and nullity of the matrix given below:

```
|0 1 2|
|0 1 0|
```

I understand a pivot element is the first nonzero element in the row, and every pivot below it needs to be further to the right than the previous pivot. But are numbers considered pivots even if you don't use them to eliminate something?

for example, the RREF of this matrix is:

```
|0 1 0|
|0 0 1|
```

I never used the 0 1 2 row to eliminate anything - yet we still consider the one in the row to be a pivot. Why?

What exactly is a pivot?

Comment: I've tried looking at formal definitions for this, and couldn't get anywhere. I was hoping working through this example would bring some clarification.

Comment: To answer your first question, the rank is the number of linearly independent columns, which also happens to equal the number of linearly independent rows.

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means, "linearly independent" I'm going to need this explained like I'm 5

Comment: so tell us what knowledge you have of linear algebra, because linear independence is the very first concept in that.

Comment: "But are numbers considered pivots even if you don't use them to eliminate something?" - The answer to this is yes. Consider the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix $\displaystyle I = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, which is already in RREF without having to do anything, and the $1$'s are pivots. "What exactly is a pivot?" - essentially, it's the element in each row that you *would* use for eliminating the corresponding entries in the other rows, if those entries are not already zero.